# How to change the Chart.js legend rectangles to squares

Tags: chart.js

I am using the Chart.js library for creating charts and everything is working fine, but my client wants to have squares in the legend instead of rectangles (I know it's a small thing, but the client is the king). Of course I could make my own legend with some HTML and CSS, but I would prefer to keep using only the library for my charts.

I hope that someone has a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a custom legend (HTML string) like this:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    legendCallback: function(chart) {
        // Return the HTML string here.
    }
  }
});
```

Reference:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Comment: Thanks! That could be my solution indeed, but I have actually no idea how to use with that function.. I tried returning a string with a h1 tag just to try it out. But it didn't show up. I did call the generateLegend() function.

Comment: You need to manually add the legend HTML into a container element, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649247/how-to-create-custom-legend-in-chartjs and (from the accepted answer) http://jsfiddle.net/vrwjfg9z/